# Adding smallest possible float to a float

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

I want to add the smallest possible value of a float to a float. So, for example, I tried doing this to get 1.0 + the smallest possible float:

```
float result = 1.0f + std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
```

But after doing that, I get the following results:

```
(result > 1.0f) == false
(result == 1.0f) == true
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Why does this happen? What can I do to get around it?

Comment: Why are you surprised? You are adding min, not epsilon.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a difference! I had assumed that they were always equivalent. Thank you, this was helpful.

Comment: @Matteo Answer? I don't really have a close reason for that question.

Comment: Worth a read: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/tricks-with-the-floating-point-format/

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter

Comment: The smallest positive value of `float` is 38 orders of magnitude smaller than 1, at 1.175e-38. The `float` type only provides six digits of precision, so adding that minimum value to 1 is tantamount to adding zero.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ because of [it's definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) (only valid if added to one).

Comment: `result += 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022250738585;` - the smallest possible `double`

Answer (score 89):

If you want the next representable value after 1, there is a function for that called [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter), from the `<cmath>` header.

```
float result = std::nextafter(1.0f, 2.0f);
```

It returns the next representable value starting from the first argument in the direction of the second argument. So if you wanted to find the next value below 1, you could do this:

```
float result = std::nextafter(1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Adding the smallest positive representable value to 1 doesn't work because the difference between 1 and the next representable value is greater than the difference between 0 and the next representable value.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` isn't quite the smallest positive representable value; it's the smallest positive normalized value, so subnormals can be lower.

Comment: IIRC, approximately half of all floating point bit-patterns represent a number with magnitude less than `1.0`.  The range of the exponent field is more or less centred around `0` (representing a `2^0 = 1.0` multiplier for the mantissa), after accounting for the bias in the way it's encoded that makes sorting FP bit-patterns as integers actually work.  See Bruce Dawson's excellent series of articles on floating-point weird stuff, including [this one about the representation](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/tricks-with-the-floating-point-format/)

Comment: See [this article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) for the table of contents in that series of FP articles.

Comment: Also, +/-Infinity makes a good second arg for `std::nextafter`, if you definitely want to go in one direction or the other.  It might possibly be faster, depending on how the implementation checks for special cases surrounding +/- 0.0.

Answer (score 43):

The "problem" you're observing is because of the **very nature** of floating point arithmetic.

In FP the precision depends on the scale; around the value `1.0` the precision is not enough to be able to differentiate between `1.0` and `1.0+min_representable` where `min_representable` is the smallest possible value greater than zero (even if we only consider the smallest normalized number, `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()`...  the smallest denormal is another few orders of magnitude smaller).

For example with double-precision 64-bit IEEE754 floating point numbers, around the scale of `x=10000000000000000` (10<sup>16</sup>) it's impossible to distinguish between `x` and `x+1`.

---

The fact that the resolution changes with scale is the very reason for the name "floating point", because the decimal point "floats". A fixed point representation instead will have a fixed resolution (for example with 16 binary digits below units you have a precision of 1/65536 ~ 0.00001).

For example in the IEEE754 32-bit floating point format there is one bit for the sign, 8 bits for the exponent and 31 bits for the mantissa:

[image: floating point]

---

The smallest value `eps` such that `1.0f + eps != 1.0f` is available as a pre-defined constant as `FLT_EPSILON`, or [`std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).  See also [machine epsilon on Wikipedia](http://machine%20epsilon), which discusses how epsilon relates to rounding errors.

I.e. epsilon is the smallest value that does what you were expecting here, making a difference when added to 1.0.

The more general version of this (for numbers other than 1.0) is called 1 unit in the last place (of the mantissa).  See Wikipedia's [ULP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

Comment: I guess the problem is rooted in people using the word "floating point" (or just "float") for "a non-integer number in a computer" without considering (or even knowing about) the actual floating nature (i.e. precision depends on scale).

Comment: Correct.  If one is going to be doing much of this sort of thing it would be a good idea to spend some time studying the concepts behind floating point.  There are a number of "surprising" effects that can occur, especially to the unaware user.

Comment: **`eps` is the wrong name for the FLT_MIN**.  `eps` is short for `FLOAT_EPSILON`, which is [the smallest number that makes a difference when added to `1.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Variant_definitions).  It's 1 unit in the last place (of the mantissa) for `1.0` (see [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)).  What you're describing is the concept of epsilon and 1 ULP, but the problem is `eps=smallest possible value greater than zero`.

Comment: corrected that for you with an edit so I could upvote this otherwise-excellent answer.  Please review to see if you like the text I added to your answer.

Comment: That would be `FLT_EPSILON`, not `FLOAT_EPSILON`. The authors of C had something against vowels.

Answer (score 20):

`min` is the smallest non-zero value that a (normalized-form) float can assume, i.e. something around 2<sup>-126</sup> (-126 is the minimum allowed exponent for a float); now, if you sum it to 1 you'll still get 1, since a `float` has just 23 bits of mantissa, so such a small change cannot be represented in such a "big" number (you would need a 126 bit mantissa to see a change summing 2<sup>-126</sup> to 1).

The minimum possible change to 1, instead, is `epsilon` (the so-called machine epsilon), which is in fact 2<sup>-23</sup> - as it affects the last bit of the mantissa.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` is the smallest positive *normalized* value. Subnormals can be lower.

Comment: @user2357112: I should add a caveat to my profile stating "any discussion I do about floating point is done disregarding denormalized numbers, which are ugly beasts best ignored" :-)

Comment: Lack of subnormals is even uglier. With subnormals available subtracting two non-equal numbers will always give a nonzero answer. Without subnormals available it won't.

Comment: @plugwash: huh, that's neat.  And that holds true even if the inputs are already denormal, because then it's just integer math on the mantissas.

Answer (score 4):

To increase/decrement a floating point value by the smallest possible amount, use `nextafter` towards +/- `infinity()`.

If you just use `next_after(x,std::numeric_limits::max())`, the result with be wrong in case `x` is infinity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
T next_above(const T& v){
    return std::nextafter(v,std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()) ;
}
template<typename T>
T next_below(const T& v){
    return std::nextafter(v,-std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()) ;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "eps   : "<<std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()<< std::endl; // gives eps

  std::cout << "after : "<<next_above(1.0) - 1.0<< std::endl; // gives eps (the definition of eps)
  std::cout << "below : "<<next_below(1.0) - 1.0<< std::endl; // gives -eps/2

  // Note: this is what next_above does:
  std::cout << std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(),
     std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) << std::endl; // gives inf

  // while this is probably not what you need:
  std::cout << std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(),
     std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) << std::endl; // gives 1.79769e+308

}
```