# Why std::floor(1 - std::numeric_limits<float>::min()) evaluates to 1

Tags: c++, limits

why do both

```
    std::cout << std::floor(1 - std::numeric_limits<float>::min());
    std::cout << std::ceil(1 - std::numeric_limits<float>::min());
```

print 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317661/adding-smallest-possible-float-to-a-float

Comment: closed as dupe since if `1 + std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` is `1` then `1 - std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` should also be `1`